# Error bars on stacked area graph with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, stacked-area-chart

I would like to add error bars on a stacked area graph created with `ggplot2`.

My csv file looks like :

```
Day  Cat  Val   Error  
0    A    0     0.00  
0    B   44.77  1.16  
0    C   54.64  0.88  
13   A   1.34   0.32  
13   B   22.78  0.45  
13   C   38.33  2.12  
19   A   1.95   0.35  
19   B   24.00  2.25  
19   C   40.30  3.86
```

I tried this :

```
ggplot(data=mydata, aes(x=Day,y=Val, group=Cat, fill=Cat,colour=Cat, ymax=Val + Error,   ymin= Val - Error)) +
 geom_area() +
 geom_errorbar(width=.5, color="black")
```

And I had this :

[image]

I'm happy with the area chart part of the graph but errors bars are not stacked on data points.

I just getting started with `R` and I really don't know what the problem is.

Besides, I've found this [tip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10417003/stacked-barplot-with-errorbars-using-ggplot2) that use `geom_segment` to avoid overlapping between bars, but I failed to use it with this code.

Thanks for helping me !

Comment: I have edited the first message :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are stacking your data but not your errorbars. To calculate the stacked version of the `ymin` and `ymax` of the errorbars you can use the `ddply` function of the `plyr` package.

```
library(plyr) 
mydata2 <- ddply(mydata,.(Day),transform,ybegin = cumsum(Val) - Error,yend = cumsum(Val) + Error)   

ggplot(data=mydata2, aes(x=Day,y=Val, fill=Cat)) +
     geom_area() +
     geom_errorbar(aes(ymax=ybegin , ymin= yend ),width=.5, color="black")
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the code! It works with my data but I get 4 times this error message : Removed 2 rows containing missing values (geom_path). I think it appears because the Error column contains few 0.

Comment: A Warning message I think (I use a French version of R)